# pandas split chunks missing rows when chunksize is small

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 8GB file, I split it into hundreds chunks, each chunk has n rows:

```
def find_contract():
    n = 100000
    global df
    for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=n,
                                          iterator=True, low_memory=False)):
        target_row= df.loc[(df.contract == 'C123')& (df.RB == '63')]
        print(target_row)
find_contract()
```

**If  n=100000 or 50000 or 40000**

it can find the target_row, but once the n

**<=30000**

the program wouldn't be able to find the target row. And also some other rows seems missing.

This looks so weird, any friend can help ?

Comment: Are you sure that each chunk contains a row matching contract == C123 and RB == 63?

Comment: yes,I'm sure ,I tested several times,!